# Does being homotopic to $0$ imply being homologous to $0$ or viceversa?

Tags: complex-analysis, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, complex-integration

For context, the question popped up while studying the homotopical version of Cauchy's Integral Theorem, and comparing it with the homological version.

**Definition:** two $γ_0, γ_1 : [0, 1] → U$ be two closed rectifiable curves in
a region $G$ are said to be ***homotopic*** iff there is a continuous function
$Γ : [0, 1] × [0, 1] → G$ such that
$$\Gamma(t,0) = \gamma_0(t), \ \ \ \ \Gamma(t,1) = \gamma_1(t), \ \ \ \ \Gamma(0,s) = \Gamma(1,s)$$
for $s,t\in[0,1]$. We say a curve $\gamma$ is ***homotopic to $0$*** iff it is homotopic to the zero curve $z\mapsto 0$.

**Definition:** two $γ_0, γ_1 : [0, 1] → U$ be two closed rectifiable curves in
a region $G$ are said to be ***homologous*** iff $w(\gamma_0,z) = w(\gamma_1,z)$ for every $z\notin G$. We say a curve $\gamma$ is ***homologous to $0$*** iff $w(\gamma,z) = 0$ for every $z\notin G$.

---

**1st Question:** does being homotopic to $0$ imply being homologous to $0$ or viceversa?

**2nd Question:** if the first question is answered in the affirmative, then certainly that one of the version of Cauchy's Integral Theorem implies the other is trivial, right?

Comment: In the definition of homotopic, you should probably have something like "$\Gamma(0,s) = \Gamma(1,s) = z_0$ for some $z_0 \in G$ \dots": the homotopy should fix the base point throughout. In the definition of homologous, what is $w$?